# Find angle $\theta$ if the following information is known

Tags: geometry

## Find $\color{green}\theta$

$\color{blue}{R_b}$ is the radius of the big circle

$R_s$ is the radius of the small circle

$\color{red}{d}$ is known

$x$ is known and is an angle

[image]

Comment: anything else is given? the answer can be any angle based on this information.

Comment: The radius of the big circle is parallel to $d$?

Comment: If I assume that the radius that you have drawn is parallel to the line $d$, then indeed the value of $\theta$ can be found.

Comment: the radius is not parallel to d, sorry for bad drawing

Answer (score 2):

Hint (Sorry for the awful drawing): Parallelity, because otherwise there are infinitely many angles that are possible, then use the [law of sines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_sines)

$$\dfrac{\sin\bar{\theta}}{R_b}=\dfrac{\sin x}{d}$$

to calculate the angle $\bar{\theta}$, then $\theta= 180°-\bar{\theta}$[image]

Comment: sorry @MrYouMath, it is not known that d is parallel to to the radius of the big circle

Comment: @ConorCosnett  If  no further info is given to govern that leftmost straight line, then $\theta$ can be any value.

Comment: @ConorCosnett: As mentioned by many comments, without additional constraints there are infinitely many solutions to the problem.